# Why (& how often) does JDBI generate "explain" queriers?

Tags: java, jdbi

I have the MyDao interface, that has this method (getByTenantId):

```
@RegisterRowMapper(MyConfigMapper.class)
public interface MyDao {
  [....]
  @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PostgresTables.MY_CONFIGS + " WHERE tenant_id = :tenantId")
  @RegisterRowMapper(MyConfigListMapper.class)
  List<MyConfig> getByTenantId(@Bind("tenantId") String tenantId);
}
```

while investigating why is this query sometimes slow, I noticed that there are two queries that my app makes to the database:

```
/* MyDao.getByTenantId */ SELECT * FROM public.my_configs WHERE tenant_id = $1
```

and

```
EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) /* MyDao.getByTenantId */ SELECT * FROM public.my_configs WHERE tenant_id = $1
```

I wasn't expecting the "EXPLAIN". Does this get issued each time? How does JDBI actually work - I was expecting it to just issue the "SELECT" query.